# Need help getting div's content to push the footer down (but divs nav tabs set the div absolute)

Tags: html, css, absolute

I'm working on a couple of aspects of someone's website and I'm having a bit of an issue with getting the tabbed navigation to display properly without absolute positioning, and as it's set to absolute the text on the Details tab overruns the "footer" sometimes. (They use a random Testimonials block which pulls varied length quotes, the short quotes cause the overrunning. If it doesn't go over please just refresh)

http://goo.gl/5Iwc1r

Normally I would put this into a jsfiddle but to get the issue to display I would practically have to copy the entire css and html of the page, which wouldn't be very efficient and certainly not very clear to look through.

So, does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to approach this problem? All advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Could you make a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Sure, here's a screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/JuZ1QyU.jpg The right side content of the page sets where the footer appears and occasionally if the testimonials on the right are short (they are randomised) it will set the footer (outlined in blue) higher than the content in the tabs (outlined in red).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish here. But I'll give it a shot...

Try adding a div underneath the tabbed navigation to act as a spacer, because of the way positioning acts upon screen real estate, this "spacer" div can keep things underneath it nice and tidy. Just set a height value to it to force the content to display where you would like it to.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This would be a solution but not an ideal one as depending on the pages the content and height of the pages change, not to mention the variable right column heigh because of the randomised testimonials. Ideally I need the content in the tabs to be what the footer clings to, not the right column. I've attached an image to show the issue http://i.imgur.com/JuZ1QyU.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way you've structured your pages, it's not going to be easy. The content is places with a `position: absolute;`. This causes the content to not push down the footer, since the height isn't registered.

I think the fastest way to solve this, without having to rebuild half your website, is by using javascript. Since I see jQuery is loaded, I shall write this using jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    setHeight();
    jQuery('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(){
        setHeight();
    });
});

function setHeight(){
    jQuery('#wrapper').height('#wrapper > div > div').is(':visible').height());
}
```

This piece of code should set the div with id `wrapper` to the height of the currently visible div.

I haven't tested this, and it is no pretty solution, but it should work.
Good luck!